# xcopy Not Surpressing File/Directory Query

Tags: windows-xp, java, prompt, xcopy

I'm attempting to use xcopy to copy over a file from one machine to another on our network as part of a Java program.  I'm calling xcopy like this:

```
xcopy "C:\Program Files\path\to\my\file" "\\othermachine\c$\Documents and Settings\<myUserName>\Desktop\Test\path\in\directory\structure\to\file" /e /y /i
```

Because I'm calling it from with in Java, I need all the prompts to be suppressed.  For the most part, \i and \y have done exactly that.  However, for this one file /i fails and I get the file or directory prompt.  The result is that it hangs the entire program.

I've also tried calling it with /s /t /q appended on to the existing options, to no avail.  Why isn't /i working to suppress the File or Directory prompt?  Is there an order I need to call the options in?  Is there something else I need to do?

EDIT: I should mention, the file is a text file - single line of text.  It does not have an extension.  It looks like this: FILE-NAME

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`echo F` does the trick:

```
echo F | xcopy "C:\Program Files\path\to\my\file" "\\othermachine\c$\Documents and Settings\<myUserName>\Desktop\Test\path\in\directory\structure\to\file" /e /y /i
```

Note that the character may differ in localized versions (my german one expects D for file (Datei) or V for directory (Verzeichnis))

Comment: no localization, it is still the same letter in Win 8 rus. However it is annoying. I'd prefer xcopy used `/-i` option to suppress this stupid question.

Comment: Unfortunately, "put a * at the end of the destination" only works if the source and destination have a three character extension. (At least, according to SS64.com.)
Sorry, this comment was meant for Govert's comment below.
echo -f worked for me (Eng US).

Answer (score 6):

A seemingly undocumented trick is to put a `*` at the end of the destination - then xcopy will copy as a file, so

`xcopy c:\source\file.txt c:\destination\newfile.txt*`

The `echo f | xcopy ...` trick does not work on localized versions of Windows, where the prompt is different.

Comment: `echo f` at least works on Russian Win 8.1 // PS. The asterisk trick works, I can only wonder who could ever discover it! I bet it is a bug in xcopy that is [ab]used to compensate for the lack of a needed feature

Answer (score 1):

This [thread on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995298/runtime-getruntime-exec-hide-the-console-screen) has no marked answer, but it may help you (seems to be the same question).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's a rather different scenario.  That's suppressing the terminal itself when calling a batch file.  I'm trying to suppress a prompt that xcopy gives.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found a useful cheat for these situations to have a text file with a Y in it and tag < y.txt on the end of the xcopy

Answer (score 0):

One more possible trick is pre-creation of a target file or folder. Then `xcopy` would not ask, because it would already know.
I would not say this solution is better than ones mentioned above, it is just different and hence I want it to be had here too.

My own simple task was copying a number of files from a network folder to a local accumulating folder.

- AAAAA\Disk1.zip => AAAAA.zip
- BBBBB\Disk1.zip => BBBBB.zip
- et cetera

Original command (one line of a slightly longer .cmd script file) was

```
for /d /r %SRC% %%1 in (*.*) do xcopy /k /f /y %%1\Disk1.zip %~dp0%%~nx1.zip
```

That however spawns a lot of those **(F)ile-or(D)-irectory** questions on a first use with new (not met before) files. Especially if I am populating a new empty target folder.

Then the `echo F` and Asterisk Hack answers - they work fine too.

- `for /d /r %SRC% %%1 in (*.*) do echo f | xcopy /k /f /y %%1\Disk1.zip %~dp0%%~nx1.zip`
- `for /d /r %SRC% %%1 in (*.*) do xcopy /k /f /y %%1\Disk1.zip %~dp0%%~nx1.zip*`

Now, yet one more potential solution would be explicitly CREATING the target folder of file right before issuing the `xcopy` command.

For file it would be, for example:

```
echo. > C:\Temp\TargetPlace
xcopy Source C:\Temp\TargetPlace
```

*Sadly Windows by default does not have `touch` command, quite useful to create dummy 0-bytes file.*

For folder it would be, for example:

```
mkdir C:\Temp\TargetPlace
xcopy Source C:\Temp\TargetPlace
```

Granted, it takes two commands - two lines - in CMD shell script.
You can not put multiple commands into CMD for loop easily, but here you can *pipe* the commands together (providing that `xcopy` would NOT actually read any user input when issued the specific command, which might change for example in future Window versions, albeit unlikely).

For folders:

```
for /d /r %SRC% %%1 in (*.*) do md %~dp0%%~nx1.zip | xcopy /k /f /y %%1\Disk1.zip %~dp0%%~nx1.zip
```

For files:

```
for /d /r %SRC% %%1 in (*.*) do echo. >%~dp0%%~nx1.zip | xcopy /k /f /y %%1\Disk1.zip %~dp0%%~nx1.zip
```

*This last command has TWO output redirections in between - `echo.` > ... | `xcopy`.  But at least in `.cmd` files of Windows 8.1 it works.*